# Cannot read property '0' of undefined, even if the data are fetched and passed to component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple table component in react.

```
const Header = ({ headers }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {headers.map((header) => (
        <th>{header}</th>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};

const Table = ({ todos }) => {
  const headers = Object.keys(todos[0]);
  return (
    <table>
      <Header headers={headers} />
    </table>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(undefined);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios.get(URL);
      setTodos(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      {loading ? <h1> loading ...</h1> : <Table todos={todos} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I receive this error from console: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined", related to todos array.

I don't understand why.

Shouldn't the table component be rendered after I got the todos from the endpoint?

Comment: Change the initial value of `todos` from `undefined` to an empty array: `useState([])`

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem because an empty array is provided to Header component that try to access the first todo to get the headers of the table.

If I change :
- const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false) to const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 
- and remove setLoading(true)

It seems to work.  But I don't know if this way is correct.
-

Comment: `todos` state is populated _after_ the initial render. This means that initial value of `todos` is passed to the `Header` component _before_ the HTTP request is made to fetch the todos. Currently you have `undefined` as the initial value, this means you are trying to do: `undefined[0]` in the `Table` component which causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first render is executed before your `useEffect()` has a chance to be executed, and since your `loading` variable is initialized with `false`, the very first render evaluates the second part of the condition, effectively trying to render your `<Table>` component.

Swap your `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);` to `true`, remove the `setLoading(true);` in your async function, and it should be good.